# Qt object management with Qt Plugins

Tags: c++, qt

My question is how to do proper object/resource management when working with Qt plugins. Default RAII does not seem to work well with Qt.

In our application we work with modules (Qt plugins) that are dynamically loaded at runtime. When loaded plugins can initialize themselves and as part of this initialization phase they can add their own widgets to the application.
- to the toolbar
- to a side panel
- etc.
Widgets that are added to the main windows have their ownership also transferred.

This all works fine, but now that our application grows more complicated we also need to pay attention to the shutdown phase. Simply unloading the modules will get us into all kinds of trouble. Objects that aren't there or types that are unloaded while their objects are still alive.

To have a reliable shutdown it seems that the only proper way to go is to do reverse initialization. This also means that every module that adds widgets to the mainwindow must remove them as well. Already trying to do this with the first widgets got me into trouble.

Module A registers widget W with the MainWindow. Preferably I would want to return a scoped object removing and deleting the widget when going out of scope. However already it seems that given widget W you cannot remove it simply from the toolbar as it works with actions (and removing the action does not delete the widget! See example below).

Concluding, it seems to me Qt is made in such a way that it gets ownership of everything and you have to rely on Qt to delete it. This does not work well with modules. I'm looking for a solution/best practice here.

Edit: 
I added an example where a module adds a custom widget to the toolbar of the MainWindow. My goal is that the module is in charge of when the widget is deleted, for the reasons stated before. The example is to make the question more concrete. It represents the generic problem - ownership of qt objects - that use this pattern in combination with plugins.

example:
**executable.cpp**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        LoadPlugin();
    }

    void LoadPlugin() {
        m_plugin = new QPluginLoader("module.dll");
        m_plugin->load();
        IModule* moduleInstance = qobject_cast<IModule*>(m_plugin->instance());
        moduleInstance->Initialize(this);
    }

    void AddToolbarSection(QWidget* widget) {
        /** ownership is transferred here to Qt */
        mainToolBar->insertWidget(pWidget);
    }

    void RemoveToolbarSection(){
        /** How to get the widget deleted? */
    }

    /** this is called before the destructor */
    void UnloadPlugin() {
        moduleInstance->Shutdown();
        m_plugin->unload();
    }

    ~MainWindow() {
        /** deletion of toolbar sections must already been done here
            as the modules are already unloaded. Otherwise access violations occur
            because specific type information is not accessible anymore.                
        */
    }

private:        
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPluginLoader* m_plugin;
    IModule* m_moduleInstance;
};
```

**module.cpp**

```
class EXPORT_MODULE IModule : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID IModuleIID)
    Q_INTERFACES(IModule)

public:
    IModule() {
    }

    void Initialize(QMainWindow* window) {
        /** QMyToolbarSectionWidget is a custom widget defined in this module (module.dll)
            it has a specific destructor and triggers all kinds application
            specific cleanup */
        m_toolbarSection = new QMyToolbarSectionWidget();
        window->AddToolbarSection(m_toolbarSection);
    }

    void Shutdown() {
        window->RemoveToolbarSection(m_toolbarSection);
    }

private:
    QWidget* m_toolbarSection;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross posting this question on the [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/61842/how-can-i-ensure-proper-resource-management-raii-when-using-qt-plugins) got me the following answer.
Even though Qt takes ownership of QWidgets/QObjects that are added to the Ui, it is still possible to delete them from the client side. Qts resource management system is built in such a way that it will know when a QObject gets deleted and it will handle this deletion by updating the UI as well as removing internal references to it. See the link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit difficult to answer since it depends on your architecture.

In general Qt's idea of cleanup is tied to the parent pointer. i.e

```
QObject *root;
QObject *leaf = new QObject();
leaf->setParent(root);
root->deleteLater();
```

QPluginLoader will even cleanup your root component on unload, so in theory, any tree below your plugin is cleared. Simply make sure that everything you return from your root is a QObject parented to your root. If it's not a QObject, wrap it in QObject.

```
class MyExtension : public QWidget {
   QAction *myAction;
   MyExtension() : QWidget() {
      myAction = new QAction(this);
   }
   QAction *getAction() {
      return myAction
   }
}
```

from your question i understand you might also be working like this:

```
class MyExtension : public QObject {
   MyWindow * myWindow;
   QAction  * myAction;
   MyExtension() : QObject() {
      myWindow = new MyWindow(this);
      myAction = new QAction(this);
   }
   void addToMainThing(TheMainThing *tmt) {
        tmt->addWidget(myAction);
   }
}
```

same thing. simply always make sure your QObject is parented to something that is parented to your plugin root.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I get how this solves my problem. I added an example to my opening post to make it more concrete. Unless I'm mistaken, you propose to make the widgets have the plugin object as owner, however that does not work as the MainWindow will steal this ownership if I understand correctly.