# Qt5.11 app plugins build error occurs: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, toolbar

I want to develop an **plugin-based Qt application**.

As one part of the app, plugins should be able to add toolbars or widgets to app's MainWindow.
I think the toolbar of plugins should be created within plugin's implementation and passed to MainWindow.

[Refer this link:Qt object management with Qt Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312928/qt-object-management-with-qt-plugins) I write my code.
I use an `on_Action_triggered()`(function no param) as slot to receive the signal of toolbar action `triggered()`, then connect the action`addShapeAction` to`on_Action_triggered()` ,using:

```
connect(addShapeAction,SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),this,SLOT(on_Action_triggered()))
```

But I got some errors when building the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bP3c.png)
such as:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2015\include\QtCore\qobject.h:320: error: C2338: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.
```

**How to solve this problem?
Is there any better way to build a toolbar of plugins?**

**Here is the code of shapeplugininterface.h**

```
#ifndef SHAPEPLUGININTERFACE_H
#define SHAPEPLUGININTERFACE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
class ShapePluginInterface{
public:
    virtual ~ShapePluginInterface(){}
    virtual QString description() = 0;
    virtual void generateShape(QString shapeType) = 0;
    virtual void Initialize(QMainWindow* window);
};
#define SHAPEPLUGININTERFACE_IID "com.geolike.shapeplugininterface"
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(ShapePluginInterface, SHAPEPLUGININTERFACE_IID)

#endif // SHAPEPLUGININTERFACE_H
```

**And here is the code of basic_shape_plugin.h:**

```
#ifndef BASIC_SHAPE_PLUGIN_H
#define BASIC_SHAPE_PLUGIN_H

#include "basic_shape_plugin_global.h"
#include "shapeplugininterface.h"
#include <QtPlugin>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>

class BASIC_SHAPE_PLUGINSHARED_EXPORT Basic_Shape_Plugin:
        public QObject,
        public ShapePluginInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "com.geolike.shapeplugininterface")
    Q_INTERFACES(ShapePluginInterface)

public:
    Basic_Shape_Plugin();
    ~Basic_Shape_Plugin();
    QString description();
    void generateShape(QString shapeType);
    void Initialize(QMainWindow* window);
public slots:
    void on_Action_triggered();
};
#endif // BASIC_SHAPE_PLUGIN_H
```

**basic_shape_plugin.cpp files:**

```
#include "basic_shape_plugin.h"

Basic_Shape_Plugin::Basic_Shape_Plugin(){}
Basic_Shape_Plugin::~Basic_Shape_Plugin(){}

QString Basic_Shape_Plugin::description()
{
    return "This is a plugin to generate shapes.";
}

void Basic_Shape_Plugin::generateShape(QString shapeType)
{
    qDebug() << shapeType;
}
void Basic_Shape_Plugin::on_Action_triggered(){
    this->generateShape("Action Triggered!");
}
void Basic_Shape_Plugin::Initialize(QMainWindow *window)
{
    QAction* addShapeAction = new QAction(window);
    connect(addShapeAction,SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),this,SLOT(on_Action_triggered()));
    QToolBar* toolBar = new QToolBar;
    toolBar->addAction("Shapes",addShapeAction);
    window->addToolBar(toolBar);
}
```

Comment: @Wafflesys I have altered the<code>on_action_triggered(bool flag)</code>, did not work too.

Comment: What do you mean by altered exactly ? You added a bool parameter to your function ? If so then their should no longer be the signal/slot signature mismatch error.

Comment: @Wafflesys I tried many times to change the definition of function on_action_triggered(), add bool parma, didn’t work for same issue, delete it, didn’t work , over and over again.

Comment: What is the code and error once you've added the bool parameter ?
The connection should be `connect(addShapeAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(on_Action_triggered(bool)));` and change also the function declaration and definition to add that bool parameter.

Fix also the other issues we can see in your error image, seems for instance that you use a . instead of a ->.

Then show us what you get.

Comment: @Wafflesys **That's false and that's not where the problems is**. A slot can have less parameters than the signal. A `void triggered(bool)` signal is *definitely* compatible with `void on_action_triggered()` slot. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addAction` method signature that you're attempting to use doesn't do what you think it does.

There are two ways to fix the code. Ideally, you should let `addAction` provide you with an action - that's what that whole convenience API was designed to do:

```
void Basic_Shape_Plugin::Initialize(QMainWindow *window)
{
    auto *toolBar = new QToolBar;
    auto *addShapeAction = toolBar->addAction("Shapes");
    connect(addShapeAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &Basic_Shape_Plugin::on_Action_triggered);
    window->addToolBar(toolBar);
}
```

Alternatively, you can create the action with the desired text yourself:

```
void Basic_Shape_Plugin::Initialize(QMainWindow *window)
{
    auto *addShapeAction = new QAction("Shapes", window);
    connect(addShapeAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &Basic_Shape_Plugin::on_Action_triggered);
    auto *toolBar = new QToolBar;
    toolBar->addAction(addShapeAction);
    window->addToolBar(toolBar);
}
```

The parentage of the action doesn't matter much - whether you create it as a child of `window`, or the `QToolBar::addAction` creates it as the parent of `toolBar`.

Comment: Worked! Thank you! and Wafflesys, thanks for your patient.

Comment: Hi, there comes another problem. I use the first code, and "Shape" action show in MainWindow, but when I click the action "Shape" in toolbar, there is nothing output. And in the mainwindow.cpp, calling generateShape("Rect") can output "Rect"! thanks again.

Comment: @LIKe As always: make a small test case. Look in my repository on github and you may find something with actions that already is close to what you want. You'll also see how to write small test cases - the whole repository is mostly 50-150 line complete Qt programs, some of them less-than-trivial.